# link path confusion after target_link_libraries call

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, matlab-deployment

I have a cmake project where I want to add a class containing the matlab engine. For compiling it I need to include two libraries `eng` and `mx`, which I do by adding

`target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libeng.so)`
`target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so)`

to my `CMakeLists.txt` file.
However there are also lots of other old versions of libraries in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/`, which seem
to be automatically added to the path as well when calling the above command. I think this causes the compiler to not find my
normal libraries anymore and produces an error.
How can I include only the two above libraries, and not all the others in the `glnxa64` folder?

---

The warning shown after running `cmake .` :

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:23 (add_executable):  
Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target CCDWidget because
files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
directories:  

runtime library [libboost_program_options.so.1.49.0] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:  
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64  
runtime library [libboost_system.so.1.49.0] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:  
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64  
runtime library [libboost_filesystem.so.1.49.0] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:  
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64  
runtime library [libboost_regex.so.1.49.0] in /usr/lib may be hidden by files in:  
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64  

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

And the error message during linking:

```
Linking CXX executable CCDWidget  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined reference to `FT_Face_GetCharVariantIndex'  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Advance'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
make[2]: ***  [CCDWidget] Error 1   
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CCDWidget.dir/all] Error 2  
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Below is my full `CMakeLists.txt` file. Lines commented out with two ## are alternatives that I tried before and didn't solve my problem. 
I also added `LINK_PRIVATE` to the target_link_libraries command as shown in the code below, which didn't make a difference.
The option `PRIVATE` alone seems to be not accepted by my cmake version, as it changed the error meassage to

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPRIVATE  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When the `#eng` line is commented out, the compilation and linking works without errors
(when calling the matlab engine is also commented out in `Readout.cpp`), so the error must be produced by that line.

---

```
#Specify the version being used as well as the language  
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)  
##cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)  
#Name your project here  
project(CCDWidget)  
set(TARGET CCDWidget)  

set(MAIN_SOURCES CCDWidget.cpp main.cc CCDControl.cpp VideoWindow.cpp ImageWindow.cpp ThisMeasurement.cpp KineticSeries.cpp FastKinetics.cpp Readout.cpp)  

##SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)  

#set_source_files_properties(Readout.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include/cpp -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/extern/include -DGLNXA64 -DGCC  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -DNDEBUG -Wno-effc++")  

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options system filesystem regex REQUIRED)  
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)  
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)  

include_directories( ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )  
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )  
include_directories( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} )  
##link_directories(/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64)  
##target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} eng)  
##target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} mx)  

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=c++11")  
add_executable( ${TARGET} ${MAIN_SOURCES} )  

target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES} )  
target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )  
target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} LINK_PRIVATE /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libeng.so)  # eng  
#target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} LINK_PRIVATE /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so ) # mx  
target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} andor )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an [imported target](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets#Importing_Targets):

```
add_library(eng SHARED IMPORTED) 
set_property(TARGET eng PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libeng.so) 
... 
add_executable( ${TARGET} ${MAIN_SOURCES} ) 
... 
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} eng)
```

For debugging you could try to build with "**make VERBOSE=1**".
This will show you the used gcc command line. 
CMake probably transforms your **target_link_libraries** command to something like:

```
g++ ... -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64 -leng ...
```

gcc then finds some boost libraries in this folder.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, but unfortunately the same error still occurs, or if I change 'SHARED' into 'MODULE' or 'STATIC' and un-comment the engine calling function, the libraries are not found anymore, and errors like
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libut.so, needed by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libeng.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
appear

Comment: the verbose output is
/usr/bin/c++   --std=c++11  ...  /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libeng.so /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013b/bin/glnxa64